# Integrate PrestaShop Webservice with Laravel 5

Tags: php, web-services, laravel-5, prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I'm trying to integrate the Prestashop 1.6 WebService into my Laravel 5.3 project to retrieve data. Has anybody ever done this or know of any link which could help me?

EDIT: My idea is, inside my Laravel app, whenever I click a specified like, it retrieves that data from my PrestaShop backoffice. For example, if I click on the Customers links inside my Laravel App, it shows the all the Customer information from currently in my PrestaShop back-office.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do? [Here](https://github.com/PrestaShop/PrestaShop-webservice-lib/tree/master/) you find the PrestaShop official web-services library

Comment: @sarcom check my EDIT

Comment: Ok. Have you already read the [official documentation](http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Using+the+PrestaShop+Web+Service)?

Comment: @sarcom Yes, I have. But I'm kind of new to Laravel. In a simple php file in the localhost, I managed to retrieve the information. In Laravel I'm not sure how that works. Do I create a controller that includes the file mentioned in the documentation and then create a method that retrieves the data and sends it to the view?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find a solution. This link: https://packagist.org/packages/protechstudio/laravel-prestashop-webservice provides a package/wrapper for most of the things that are in the documentation to integrate the webservice inside of a Laravel app. 

Although to be honest, the documentation on either website is not very clarifying and I had to discover a lot of stuff by myself.

Comment: hi @Adam if i want to use Prestashop users data to login to my Laravel, is that i can do it the same way?

Comment: Hey @JovenDev I'm guessing you can, just instead of checking your database for the user data, check if that login information exists in the users data from Prestashop. Basically in the login process, the user data from Prestashop will be used instead of a local database. Don't know if that answered your question..

Comment: Hey @AdamSilva that's mean I have to modified my Auth Login Controller? Do you have any sample coding?

Comment: Not at the moment. But check out the `AuthenticatesUsers` trait and everything should be there. Then it's just a matter of overriding the functions you need to change.