# Import Prestashop api into laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, prestashop

I'm trying to import Prestashop webservice in a Laravel 5 project to use it in a command.

This is the file path:

```
app/ecommerce/prestashop/PSWebServiceLibrary.php
```

And this is the structure of the file:

```
    <?php


    namespace app/ecommerce/prestashop/;

    use \Exception;



  class PrestaShopWebservice
    {
    }

class PrestaShopWebserviceException extends Exception { }
```

But when I try to import this file to a controller like this:

```
use \App\ecommerce\prestashop\PSWebServiceLibrary;

$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($store_path, $auth_key, false);
```

I get this error:

```
[Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalErrorException]                                       
  Class 'App\EcommercePlatforms\Prestashop\PSWebServiceLibrary\PrestaShopWebservice' not found
```

Comment: The error is telling you exactly what's wrong: The class isn't found. If you haven't imported your components using Composer, then you need to `require` them, or set up [PSR-4 autoloading](https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#psr-4).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39518297/integrate-prestashop-webservice-with-laravel-5?noredirect=1#comment66451178_39518297